# Macro enabled Word document is not saving

Tags: vba, ms-word

We recently deployed a macro enabled Word document at our organization. For most users, it works fine. For about a third of users, however, a few different save errors pop up.

1. Users click the save icon but nothing happens, the document doesn't save
2. Word says the disk is full (and therefore the document cannot save) when it isn't full

We've tried saving under different names and to different directories, which does not fix the error. We've also tried saving as a .docx when done using the macros, but for these users, it undo's the changes made by the macro.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing the code nobody will be able to help you. Please read [ask] and [repro] - these articles will help you to improve your question.

Comment: it would also help to know whether this is on Windows or macOS.

Comment: If it has macros, you have to save it as a macro enabled file using the correct extension. If you had shown us your code, we could probably explain where you went wrong, but you did not include your code.

Comment: Showing the code won't help, because the problem is with file permissions, renaming and deleting temporary files.